# How to apply the gmnl function in R for a latent class analysis of a discrete choice experiement?

Tags: r

I try to perform a latent class analysis on my data from a discrete choice experiment. The respondents needed to chose between 2 options with as attributes: the number of children they prefer, and the educational level they prefer for their children (stated as a mixture of the number of children). The first rows of my data look like this:

```r
Respondent Block Choice card Chosen FNoPrimary  FPrimary FSecondary FTertiary MNoPrimary
 1          1           1      1    0.0000000  0.0000000   0.00     0.0000000  0.0000000
 1          1           1      0    0.3333333  0.6666667   0.00     0.0000000  0.0000000
 1          2          12      0    0.3333333  0.3333333   0.00     0.0000000  0.0000000
 1          2          12      1    0.1666667  0.0000000   0.00     0.3333333  0.1666667
 1          3           2      0    0.0000000  0.0000000   1.00     0.0000000  0.0000000
 1          3           2      1    0.0000000  0.0000000   0.25     0.0000000  0.0000000
  MPrimary MSecondary MTertiary NChildren Age District   Religion Indigenous Ethnic group    Sex
1        0       1.00 0.0000000         1  18        0 Protestant          0      Wolaita Female
2        0       0.00 0.0000000         3  18        0 Protestant          0      Wolaita Female
3        0       0.00 0.3333333         9  18        0 Protestant          0      Wolaita Female
4        0       0.00 0.3333333        12  18        0 Protestant          0      Wolaita Female
5        0       0.00 0.0000000         1  18        0 Protestant          0      Wolaita Female
6        0       0.25 0.5000000         4  18        0 Protestant          0      Wolaita Female
       Educational level Studentornot Farmerornot Marital status Having children Ever used contraception
1 High school - grade 10            1           0              0               0                       0
2 High school - grade 10            1           0              0               0                       0
3 High school - grade 10            1           0              0               0                       0
4 High school - grade 10            1           0              0               0                       0
5 High school - grade 10            1           0              0               0                       0
6 High school - grade 10            1           0              0               0                       0
  Alternative
1           1
2           2
3           1
4           2
5           1
6           2
```

I looked at all the packages available in R and I think that only the gmnl package can handle my type of data and is able to add covariates. However, if I compare the output of my latent class analysis for a simple linear model with only 2 covariates (age and district) (as stated below), I become a totally different output for the parameter estimates and the loglikelihood (-2598.6 in Stata vs -2495.5 in R) then when I perform the same analysis with Stata (see code below).

in R:

```r
defining_data <- mlogit.data(final_data_alternativeadded, id.var = "Respondent", choice = "Chosen", alt.var = "Alternative", chid.var="Choice.card", group.var = "Block", varying = 7:15, shape = "long")
mnl <- gmnl(Chosen ~ 1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + z | 0 | 0 | 0 | Age + District, data = defining_data, model = 'lc', Q = 3) 
summary(mnl)
```

in Stata:

```r
ssc install lclogit
ssc install fmlogit
lclogit chosen fprimary fsecondary ftertiary mnoprimary mprimary msecondary mtertiary block nchildren, group(choicecard) id(respondent) nclasses(3) membership(age district)
```

I tried to make all my variables numeric, to multiply the mixture proportions by the number of children to get values which are closer to each other, to order my dataset based on the value of the number of choice cards per respondents... but I always get other values for the latent class probabilities. Does someone know why? I know that lclogit in Stata uses the Expectation Maximization algorithm and gmnl in R the Maximum Likelihood approach but I don't think that the parameter estimates and the loglikelihood can completely differ because of that.

I also tried it with with an existing open dataset:

Stata:

```r
use http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/t/traindata.dta, clear
ssc install lclogit
ssc install fmlogit
lclogit y price contract local wknown tod seasonal, group(gid) id(pid) nclasses(3) seed(12345)
```

R:

```r
getwd()
traindata <- read.xlsx("traindata.xlsx", 1, header = TRUE)
library(mlogit)
library(gmnl)
traindata[1:nrow(traindata),11] <- seq(1,4) #to add a column with the alternatives per choice numbered from 1 to 4
names(traindata) <- c('y', 'price', 'contract', 'local', 'wknown', 'tod', 'seasonal', 'gid', 'pid', 'X_xi', 'Alternative')
TM <- mlogit.data(traindata, choice = "y", id.var = "pid", alt.var = "Alternative", chid.var = "gid", shape = "long")
mnl <- gmnl(y ~ price + contract + local + wknown + tod + seasonal | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1, data = TM, model = 'lc', Q = 3)
summary(mnl)
```

However, Stata states that they become a loglikelihood of -1117.9987 while R becomes -1329.5 and both have totally different parameter estimations.

Does someone know why this is the case?

Thank you very much in advance

Kind regards

Eva

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things here that might be useful to think about.

You would expect some minor differences between the two because i) latent class models are susceptible to converging to different local optima depending on starting values and ii) the expectation maximization algorithm is more likely to compared to maximum likelihood. However, this is unlikely to be the case here.

What is likely the issue is that Stata takes into consideration the panel structure of the data, whereas in R you have specified a cross-sectional latent class model treating each observation as independent. The large difference in LL value is a strong indicator of this.

Try this instead (with `panel = TRUE`):

```
mnl <- gmnl(y ~ price + contract + local + wknown + tod + seasonal | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1,
 data = TM, model = 'lc', Q = 3, panel = TRUE)
```